# Reader close and dispose

Tags: ado.net, sqldatareader

Please look at the code. we have a method like this which returns reader. ie

```
public IRecordsReader GetValues()
{
   IRecordsReader TestReader.....

   return TestReader;
}
```

and we are calling that method inside another method like this

```
IRecordsReader ResultReader = GetValues();
ResultReader.Close();
ResultReader.Dispose();
```

ie we are closing and disposing that reader.

My doubt is that we are not properly closing the TestReader in the `GetValues()` method. So whether it will cause any connection pool issues? Please give your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably wrap your SqlDataReader with using so that it would automatically close and dispose the `IDisposable` object.

#### Like below

```
using(IRecordsReader ResultReader = GetValues())
{
//do your stuff
}
//resultReader is closed and disposed from now
```

#### More Info

since you do this

```
public IRecordsReader GetValues()
{
   IRecordsReader TestReader.....

   return TestReader;
}
```

and this

`IRecordsReader ResultReader = GetValues()`

this is what you are actually doing

`IRecordsReader ResultReader = TestReader`

so you are indirectly closing/disposing the `TestReader` instance. You get it?. Put it in code and try you will know :)

#### Answer

OP Asked -`So whether it will cause any connection pool issues? Please give your suggestions.`

Unless your connection limit is not exceeded you won't have a issue. But since you are closing and disposing the resource you will not have any issues :)

Comment: But my doubt is not about closing ResultsReader but about closing TestReader.

Comment: So thats what i am doing now, after receiving the TestReade to ResultsReader , i 'm closing and disposing ResultsReader. So i think what i'm doing is same as that you told?

Comment: @mahesh see my answer. Since you close the connection and dispose it you should not have any pooling problems

Comment: @mahesh Yup. & my code would save you few key strokes and CLR doing cleanup automaticaly.